# How do you parse Ajax/Jquery response data using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, ajax

my apologies if I used incorrect terms in my title. I am not sure how else to put this.

I am using Ajax to make a GET call and it responds with data in the form of html/txt/json etc. all in one file. I am trying to extract only whats in between [{ }].

I have successfully used the regex below to achieve this using https://regexr.com:

```
(?=\[\{).*(\}\])
```

On this response data returned by my GET call:

```
Lots of random text, random html, etc. 
[{There is text in here hello world}]
Lots of random text, random html, etc.
```

As you can see this regex will properly extract this:

```
[{There is text in here hello world}]
```

This works great! But I just can't seem to figure out how to automatically parse the data after I get the response. I am currently trying:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response.replace(/(?=\[\{).*(\}\])/));
});
```

But this isn't working. Am I going at this completely wrong? It's only outputting the full GET response and not the regex data. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your `response` is a string, then [string.match()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) could be useful.

Comment: @Geshode this was exactly what I needed. Sub as an answer and I will Approve it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad, that I could help. I wrote a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your response is a string, then you could use [string.match()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) like this:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response.match(/(?=\[\{).*(\}\])/));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `.indexOf()` to find the indices of `{` and `}`:

`var first_index = indexOf("{");`

`var second_index = indexOf("}"):`

Once you find the indices, define a substring based on these indices:

`var parsed_string = response.substring(first_index + 1, second_index);`

You will need to add 1 to the `first_index` variable so that you do not get the `"{"` in the `parsed_string` variable.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5y1g9780/5/)

Answer (score 0):

The more robust method would be to request the data in JSON, parse it accordingly then do javascript stuff with it:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
// do js stuff with obj
```